# Web development project management through Jira Software

Tags: scrum, agile, jira, design

I worked as a software developer and recently I became the manager of some web development projects for clients. Can you please recommended some useful tutorials for web development project management through Jira Software?

Answer (score 1):

Jira is simply a tool. You probably want to look at Scrum or Kanban for the actual process approaches.

The book "Kanban" by David Anderson is pretty much the go-to source for information on that.

For Scrum, the [Scrum Guide](https://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html) is a great starting point.

Comment: I have a good understanding about scrum and kanban. I want to know about how these concepts use in web development project